# ESP8266 - NodeMCU in stationap mode

Tags: wifi, esp8266, nodemcu

Is there a way I can put NodeMCU in STATIONAP mode and communicate between two networks (the network which the esp8266 is the access point and the network which the esp8266 is the station)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the way that you mentioned does it. Use the commands below :

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATIONAP);
wifi.ap.config({ssid = YOUR_AP_NAME});
wifi.ap.setip({ip = DESIRED_AP_IP, netmask = DESIRED_AP_MASK, gateway = DESIRED_AP_GW});
wifi.sta.config(SSID, PASS);
wifi.sta.connect();
```